# Conversion of Unicode to List type in python

Tags: python, mod-python

The below one is working properly,

```
>>> a = 1,2
>>> a = u'[1,2]'
>>> print a
[1,2]
>>> type(a)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> n = [e.encode('utf-8') for e in a.strip('[]').split(',')]
>>> n
['1', '2']
>>> type(n)
<type 'list'>
```

#

But when include it in the program. Instead of changing the value from unicode to list, its just changing the variable name.

```
>>> a = 1,2
>>> a = u'[a]'
>>> print a
[a]  # Instead of 1,2.
```

Please help me on this.,

Comment: What do you think `a = u'[a]'` is supposed to do?  Do you think it does some kind of conversion?  Where did you see that?

Comment: What are you trying to do, for real? Because this doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

when you make `a = u'[a]'` you are not using the initial variable `a` put inside a list but the characters `'[a]'`

```
>> a = 1,2
>> a = u'[what?]'
>> print a
[what?]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, what you are looking for is `unicode` function

```
>>> a = 1,2
>>> a
(1, 2)
>>> unicode(a)
u'(1, 2)'
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> unicode(a)
u'[1, 2]'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

This does what you apparently are trying to do:

```
>>> a = 1,2
>>> print a
1,2
```

What you really need to do is beyond me. There is no practical reason to convert a list to unicode, really.